# Autofac RegisterAssemblyTypes Injects Null in constructor parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, autofac, autofac-configuration

The class

```
public class CustomerRepository : ICustomer
{
   public CustomerRepository(IEmailManager emailManager)
   {
     ...
   }
}
```

Autofac config

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

builder.RegisterModule<AutofacWebTypesModule>();

builder.RegisterType<EmailManager>()
        .As<IEmailManager>()
        .SingleInstance();

builder.RegisterType<CustomerRepository>()
        .As<ICustomer>();

foreach (var assembly in assemblies)
{
    builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assembly)
            .Except<CustomerRepository>()
            .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Repository"))
            .AsImplementedInterfaces();
}

var container = builder.Build();
DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
```

Let's ignore that a repository shouldn't be emailing customers.  Not my code.  It's being refactored.

If I use the foreach loop to register assembly types, when CustomerRepository is creates, the email manager is always null.

If I remove the loop to register assembly types, CustomerRepository is created with a valid email manager.

Why is calling RegisterAssemblyTypes preventing the creation of the email manager?

Things I've tried,

1. Registering Assembly types first. Then the individual types.
2. Removing the Except clause from the RegisterAssemblyTypes query.
3. Registering EmailManager without the SingleInstance constraint.

Comment: This may be environmental. Seems to work fine in [test code](https://dotnetfiddle.net/mlVRbH)

Comment: Seems so.  I've found that if I register one specific repository, Email Manger does not get instantiated.  I've stripped out all the code from that repository except for the required interface members and still it fails.  No exception, just a null value for Email Manager.

Comment: so the answer is I had two constructors and I totally missed the second constructor. When I registered the other type, Autofac (and Unity) used the constructor with the most arguments and  and bypassed the constructor I expected to be used.

Answer (score 0):

The CustomerRepository class had two constructors and I totally missed the second constructor. When I registered the other type, Autofac (and Unity) used the constructor with the most arguments and and bypassed the constructor I expected to be used.  EmailManager was never injected because it wasn't in the second constructor.